# Ready event on cached pages?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to fire some code whenever a page is shown in the browser:

```
$(function() {
   console.log('got ready event!');
});
```

This event gets fired only when the browser downloads the page. If I navigate to a different page, then go back, the above snippet won't be fired. It seems that the browser caches the page state, because the server does not receive any requests when the page is shown.
So when I go back to the page, it restores the cached page state without firing the `ready` event.

Is there an event I can listen to whenever the page is shown, regardless of whether the page is cached or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The directive `cashe-control:no-cashe` indicates cached information should not be used and instead requests should be forwarded to the origin server.

```
<meta http-equiv="cashe-control" content="no-cashe">
```

---

Try the [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event) event:

> This event works the same as the load event, except that it fires every time the page is loaded. The first time the page loads, the pageshow event fires just after the firing of the load event. The pageshow event uses a boolean property called persisted that is set to false on the initial load. It is set to true if it is not the initial load (in other words, it is set to true when the page is cached).

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function(){
   // ...
})
```

Comment: I'm okay with the browser caching the page. That would save a lot of unnecessary traffic. But I'd like to fire the `ready` event even if the page is cached.

Comment: @SamadLotia have you tried [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_firefox_1.5_caching#pageshow_event) event?

Comment: `$(document).bind('pageshow', function() { ... })` doesn't work, but `window.onpageshow = function() { ... }` does on Chrome & FF.

Comment: Did you mean `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">`? Its written `cashe` in your example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event <-- updated pageshow mdn link

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old case but I've struggled with this, too. "pageshow" can do this job, but it seems like you have to bind this event to window instead of document. So, the code have to look like this:

```
$(window).on('pageshow', function(){ alert('page show'); });
```